# Crash with UITabBarController

Tags: ios

Sometimes I have strange crash when I switch from one tab to another:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3857e636 objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                               0x3024ca89 -[UIResponder(Internal) _canBecomeFirstResponder] + 21
2   UIKit                               0x3024c7a3 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 207
3   UIKit                               0x3024caff -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 107
4   UIKit                               0x302c946b -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 47
5   UIKit                               0x302ca345 -[UIView(Hierarchy) deferredBecomeFirstResponder] + 57
6   UIKit                               0x301cd441 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 165
7   Foundation                          0x2e304d33 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 211
8   UIKit                               0x301cd291 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 297
9   UIKit                               0x301da01d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1413
10  UIKit                               0x301d9a93 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 31
11  UIKit                               0x302bb563 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 979
12  UIKit                               0x302fb783 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 31
13  UIKit                               0x302fb759 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 105
14  UIKit                               0x302fa87b -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1107
15  UIKit                               0x302fa41f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 39
16  UIKit                               0x302fa2f7 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 259
17  UIKit                               0x303c45c9 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 273
18  UIKit                               0x302036c7 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
19  UIKit                               0x30203663 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 39
20  UIKit                               0x303c447f -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 371
21  UIKit                               0x302036c7 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
22  UIKit                               0x30203663 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 39
23  UIKit                               0x30203633 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 47
24  UIKit                               0x301eed7b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 375
25  UIKit                               0x303c41a7 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 119
26  UIKit                               0x302036c7 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
27  UIKit                               0x30203663 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 39
28  UIKit                               0x30203633 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 47
29  UIKit                               0x301eed7b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 375
30  UIKit                               0x3020307b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 595
31  UIKit                               0x30202d4d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 529
32  UIKit                               0x301fdca7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 759
33  UIKit                               0x301d2e75 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 197
34  UIKit                               0x301d1541 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7121
```

Maybe for someone this will look familiar and he could help to understand root of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same crash log.And my reason is  the view controller is released but the UITextField.delegate is not setting nil. So you can set UITextField.delegate = nil in dealloc of the view controller.